# Tub to shower conversion plumbing issues

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

[image][image][image][image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]This is a long one….. I’ll start by saying, I’m a complete amateur when it comes] to plumbing- only knowledge is recent research. 7 years ago I had a tub to shower conversion in an older house.

The previous tub was one of the “walk in” tubs typically for the elderly (do not know any specific details about the install). I had a plastic stand up shower fixture installed. Over the last 4 years the shower backs up and will not drain until after water is turned off (takes around 5 mins). Typically, after weeks of dealing with this, I call a plumber, they go in on the roof and clean the stack? Problem solved for a few months.

Most recently, 2 month ago… this is where the big issue begins… I started smelling what I thought was mold in my bathroom. Had a mold inspector come out (agreed they could smell mold) but it was not visible anywhere. Very unusual for the strong odor. Had an air test, no mold. I decided every time I shower, I smell the mold stronger, so I smelled the drain… WOW!! Found the problem. Called a plumber.. was told the plumbers who installed the shower “cut corners” and connected the old plumbing to the new and according to him, this was incorrect due to where the old ptrap was located- causing sewer gas to escape into my home and possibly a leak underneath. His reaction to the drain smell was very telling!! Apparently, my ptrap has failed and will need to be replaced by removing the current shower fixture, busting concrete, adding a ptrap under the shower, adding tile and installing a new shower.. which will also require drywall repairs? I can now smell the “mold” coming from my 2nd bathroom toilet and kitchen sink..

Any advice on what’s going on here and if this new info I’ve received about ptrap location is accurate would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Do you have a room below the trap?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is specifically a Question & Answer site, not a general discussion forum. The only question I see here is, "which will also require drywall repairs?" and yes, if you're redoing your bathroom, you'll probably have to do some drywall repair work. You've really given us no question to answer and, frankly, not enough detail to answer the implied question "is my contractor right?". Some pictures of the setup would be helpful, (you can [edit] them in). However, it's likely that your new plumber is correct.

Comment: No room below the trap.  Single story house, no basement.

Comment: Questions- will I need to relocate the trap? Was the tub to shower conversion done incorrectly by connecting old plumbing to new, and not relocating trap? Older home with metal pipes/traps. What is causing the sewer gas to come up through kitchen (other end of house) and 2nd bathroom? I will edit in photos.